# EC2 Image Builder with Amazon Inspector - different rule packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, ec2-ami, amazon-inspector

I've built golden image pipeline with EC2 Image Builder. It works perfectly fine.

Now I want to integrate it with Amazon Inspector and there is aws-managed test component which I can add easily to my pipeline - **inspector-test-linux**.
The issue here for me is that it uses the 'CIS Operating System Security Configuration Benchmarks-1.0' rule package. I want to use another, simpler package - 'Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures-1.1' but didn't manage to find any options on how to achieve that. Question here is is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The *inspector-test-component* AWS managed component is pre-built for performing CIS assessments with Amazon Inspector in EC2 Image Builder.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/imagebuilder/latest/userguide/how-image-builder-works.html#image-builder-compliance

You would need to create a custom scripted component to use a different set of package with Amazon Inspector. Another option is to create a component to only install Amazon Inspector agent in the build process, and run checks outside the image building process when an instance is spun up from the image.